# Running a VM on SD card

Tags: virtualbox, ssd, sd-card

I recently bought a ssd, and i'm wondering if running a windows virtual machine will do a lot of writing or it's mainly reads?

I thought using a 32G SD card (SanDisk extreme plus 80m/s read and 60m/s write) to run the VM without wearing out the ssd. Since my card reader is on PCI, it should perform just as if it was installed on a HDD (60m/s write), right? Also i'm thinking on setting a swap partition on SD card since i did not set a swap partition on SSD, is that advised?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear, what is your VM host OS? Linux? And you want to install Windows as a VM guest OS? How many RAM in your computer?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 13.10, and i want to run windows as guest OS. I have 8GB ram

Comment: Not really an answer, but I have been running a Windows WM in a SSD for at least two years without any problems. And SMART reports the SSD healthy.

Comment: It's not really 'will OS on SSD be bad' - it entirely depends on what that OS is going to be doing. A customized distro just for rendering is going to thrash that disk a lot more than an average desktop Windows 7/8 installation. What do you see yourself doing for the most part with the VM?

Answer (score 1):

Do not set a swap partition on the SD card. If you are running your host on an SSD then you don't need a swap partition, if you want one anyways it should be placed on a medium of equal to or higher speeds to prevent it from slowing down your system.

If you want to run a Windows vm off an sd card you can do so, but I would be wary of poor performance. The card you listed sounds fast, but often times cards don't get the max speed across the entire card. I tried to find the product page for your card and this is the page I found:

http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/sd/extremeplus/

The first thing I read when visiting the product page was "With read speeds as fast as 80MB/s", which suggests that at times you will experience lower speeds and there is no guarantee that you will ever see the 80MB/s. However this card is intended for use in devices that do several MB/s writes so you may be okay. I would not advise it though. VMs often don't get the full device performance which will amplify any short comings.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, VirtualBox does not use swap, it always use RAM. So, swap will be used for other applications. I don't think you need swap with 8Gb RAM. It would be better to buy more RAM if it's not enough.

To achieve maximum speed on reed/write operations you need some additional filesystem parameters to be set on SD-card. I did it myself using this guide http://blogofterje.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/optimizing-fs-on-sd-card/ . But, comparing with HDD the speed will be lower.

Comment: VirtualBox uses swap for sure. Some parts of the guest OS (the kernel mainly) can't be swapped, but most can.